# CAML-Query with Lookups

Tags: 2010, list, caml-query

From those two lists:

```
AVAILABLEDATES
-date (DateTime)
-maxBookings (Number)

BOOKINGS
-availableDate (Lookup to AVAILABLEDATES:Id)
-User (Person)
```

I need to get all dates that their bookings don't reach maxBookings. In SQL it would be something like this:

```
SELECT ad.date
FROM AvailableDates ad
WHERE ad.maxBookings > (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Bookings b WHERE b.availableDate = ad.Id)
```

How can I accomplish the same result via CAML-Query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I used LINQ to accomplish it. [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/74006893-4a6b-45dd-af12-f8a473c493c0/join-sharepoint-lists-via-caml-or-linq?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious) you can see an example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a CAML join like

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Join = ...
```

Have a look on the following link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539975(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: But how can I compare maxBookings with elements returned? I know I can do it programatically, but I'd prefer using only a query. Or, at least, find the most efficient solution possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have populated your look up column, then for CAML Query you can do something like this.

```
<Query>
       <Where>
              <Eq>
                  <FieldRef Name="availableDate" />
                  <Value Type="Choice">
                         The value you want to specify
                  </Value>
              </Eq>
       </Where>
</Query>
```

Using enumerator etc. you can get the count for your bookings list and then you can check against your other list.